# Why is orient.getDatabase() returning a null related error? OrientDB

Tags: nosql, orientdb

`return orient.getDatabase();`

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDatabase' of null\nTypeError: Cannot read property 'getDatabase' of null"`

Why is OrientDB returning null when I'm trying to get the database?

Just doing "return orient" doesn't do anything and I tried using the command on the demo database, but it's still returning the same error?

The documentation doesn't really tell me what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer if anyone needs it.
In the newer version, you no longer have to use

`orient.getDatabase()`, it's enough to write `db`.